Completed divided power algebra
Let $X$ be a scheme of characteristic $p$ and $E$ a locally free sheaf on $X$. Given a connection $\nabla$ on $F = \mathcal{O}_X \oplus E$. Take $\mathcal{A} = \varinjlim \operatorname{Sym}^n F \simeq \operatorname{Sym} E$, where the morphisms $\operatorname{Sym}^n F \to \operatorname{Sym}^{n+1}F$ arises from the injection $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $F$. Let $I$ be the ideal in $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $E$. Let $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ be the completed divided power algebra.
It is said in Nonabelian Hodge Theory in Characteristic $p$, section 2.2 that the connection $\nabla$ extends to $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$, which follows from BO 6.2 that closed immersion pushing structure sheaf forward to crystals. I can't see the relations. Besides, I am not familiar with such completed staff. For example, should the connection or everything related be continuous?
